# Javascript shows the year 2014 instead of 2013 using php date string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I have a website and i want to display the `PHP` generated date through `JavaScript` and `jQuery`. The problem is, when i save the date string returned by `PHP Date("d-m-Y H:i:s")` function and pass this string to `JavaScript new Date()` function, it displays the next year rather than the current. For example, right now the year is 2013, but is shows 2014 instead. Below is my code to better explain my problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     var phpDateString = "<?php echo Date("d-m-Y H:i:s");?>"
     alert(phpDateString); // Displays: 13-12-2013 01:49:17 (this is correct date)

     var date = new Date(Date.parse(phpDateString));
     alert(date); //Displays: Sun Jan 12 2014 01:53:20 (this is incorrect date)  
 });
```

I am using localhost `Xampp Server` and i have changed its `timezone` to `date.timezone=Asia/Karachi` in `php.ini` file. Why this is happening. Would be great if someone helps me out.

Comment: Actually, you've found a wormhole and have teleported into the future with your computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript is expecting `MM-DD-YYYY` but you are giving it `DD-MM-YYYY`. So it is turning `13` into `1` and thus you get January instead of December and an additional year being added. Because today is `12/12` it is a coincidence that the day is correct otherwise that would be wrong, too.